# camel with netty4-http - EncoderException

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I'm using camel 2.14.0 with netty4-http
and I get the following  exception.

the scenario is this: 
I have a route that sends a request, waits for the response (inOut) and then sends another request.
the first request works, and then the second one fails.

also, if I do it quickly enough after the failure - the first request will also fail.

while debugging a bit (HttpObjectEncoder) - I saw that in the working flow the state of the request is: state = ST_INIT (0)
and in the request that failed it is: ST_CONTENT_NON_CHUNK (1)
which causes the illegal state when the type of message is HttpMessage

is this a bug or is there anything I can configure to fix it?

> Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultFullHttpRequest
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
>       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:192)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:658)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$2000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:939)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:991)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:924)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultFullHttpRequest
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encode(HttpObjectEncoder.java:63)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Encoder.encode(HttpClientCodec.java:106)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
>       ... 10 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to identify the problem:

the first request I sent was a GET request with null body.
in the class org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpProducer - 
the method getRequestBody(Exchange exchange) is creating the actual request object from the exchange.
in it - the method "toNettyRequest" in class org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.DefaultNettyHttpBinding
checks if the body is null, and if so - it is creating a DefaultHttpRequest, and not DefaultHttpFullRequest

when the request reaches the encoder as a result of a writeAndFlush call - the encoder does not clean its state because of this part of the code:

```
 if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
    state = ST_INIT;
 }
```

the DefaultHttpRequest is not instanceof LastHttpContent, so the state remains ST_CONTENT_NON_CHUNK  and the next request will get an IllegalStateException because the state is not ST_INIT

this bug did not exist in netty-http, it only happened when I moved to use netty4-http

the workaround is simple - use an empty String ("") as body